# What is the best way to keep the sitemap.xml updated

Tags: node.js, angular, express, seo, sitemap

We have a job portal website built with **MEAN Stack** with over **100,000** active jobs and **1,000** active company profile pages. 
This data is completely dynamic. Every day tens of job postings and companies are registered. 
The problem is that we should keep the `sitemap.xml` file(s) always updated with the latest active links.

Does anybody know the best practice to keep the `sitemap.xml` always updated in such a dynamic website?

Answer (score 1):

In your express app you can add a sitemap.xml route like so

```
const xml = require('xml');
... // other routes

app.get('/sitemap.xml', function (req, res) {
   // get routes from database or others
   response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
   response.send(xml(jobs));
})
```

Your `jobs` could contain last edited date and the url to your jobs so it could be very accurate.

Or there are packages like [express-sitemap-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sitemap-xml) you can use that uses a great example to get routes from a database and generates a `sitemap.xml`

```
const express = require('express')
const expressSitemapXml = require('express-sitemap-xml')

const app = express()

app.use(expressSitemapXml(getUrls, 'https://bitmidi.com'))

async function getUrls () {
  return await getUrlsFromDatabase() // this function would be to get your database jobs into an object
}
```